# Proving unit relation features

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, relations

I am trying to prove the following unit relation features:

$R ⊆ X × X$,

$IdX ◦ R = R ◦ IdX = R.$

How do I go about doing it?

Comment: Use the axiom of extensionality, i.e., prove that any element of one set is the element of the other and vice versa.

Comment: IdX = ∀ x :{(x,x)| x⊆X}, like this? I am not sure how to turn relation R into this tho.

Comment: First we have $id_X = \{(x , x) \in X \times X: x = x\}$ and $R \subseteq X  \times X$. And we have that $id_X \circ R = \{(x, y) \in dom(R) \times ran(id_X): \exists z\in ran(R)((x, z) \in R \wedge (z, y) \in id_X \}$ Now for all $t \in id_X \circ R$ we have $t = (x, y)$ for some $x, y \in X$ (why? (Use the definition of composition)). Now use the above definitions to solve the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(x,z)\in\mathsf{Id}_X\circ R\iff \exists y\;[(x,y)\in R\wedge (y,z)\in\mathsf{Id}_X]\tag1$$

Now realize the $(y,z)\in\mathsf{Id}_X$ is true if and only if $y=z$ so $(1)$ can be rewritten as:$$(x,z)\in\mathsf{Id}_X\circ R\iff(x,z)\in R$$

This tells us exactly that: $$\mathsf{Id}_X\circ R=R$$ as was to be shown.

Try to find a similar proof for the other equality.